# How to set OnFocousChangeListener for an EditText which is inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment in which I have a TextView, an ImageView and an EditText. I am using this fragment at multiple places as input fields. Now I have implemented OnFocousChangeListener and i want to set OnFocousChange for all fileds but I am not knowing how to get id for EditText which is inside the fragment. Moreover if I am trying to get id by using getId() every EditText inside the fragment is giving same id. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. Make your fragment implements `OnFocusChangeListener`.

Then,

In:

```
public void onfocusChange(view v) {
    switch(v.getId) {
         case R.id.edittext1:                
             ///Your logic
             break;
    }
}
```